# There is a problem granting permissions at runtime

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I have a weird bug, I have an app that registers a Brodcast whenever I call to a number it pops up a webpage.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        registerBrodcasts();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Brodcast registered.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }


private void registerBrodcasts(){
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");
        registerReceiver(new CallReceiver(), filter);
    }



  @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                boolean phoneLogsPermission = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                boolean phoneCallPermision = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                if (phoneLogsPermission && phoneCallPermision) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions granted, we can call now.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please give permissions to the app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

So, this is how it works, When I open my app it pops up the two permissions I need to request, **Phone Call** and **Phone Logs** meanwhile I'm giving access to this permissions **registerBrodcasts();** have launched and registered my brodcast.

But here is the bug, If I request the permissions at runtime and try to call after giving this permissions my brodcast does not launch, but, if I go to the app settings and give them manually, the brodcast works without problems.

I dont know why from my app giving this permissions does not register my brodcast but giving them manually does.

This is the brodcast

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

        Toast.makeText(context, "Intercepted call " + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (phoneNumber.equals("123456789")) {

            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://myweb.com"));
            browserIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(browserIntent);
        }

    }
}
```

I suspect that when I give the permissions to the app, my brodcast has been registered without such permissions, but If I move the **registerBrodcasts()** method to my **onRequestPermissionResults** it also does not work

These are all my permissions, which I only need to ask for **call_phone and read_call_logs**

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```

Comment: `There is a problem granting permissions at runtime` You cannot grant anything. You can only request them and that is what you do. The user can grant them.

Comment: but why does this app registers the brodcasts if I grant them manually from settings and not from the app itself ?

Comment: Because if the user grants it it does not registers the brodcast

Comment: `registerBrodcasts();` I would call that only just before finish(). On those two places. And when will you unregister ?

Comment: I called it inside the onRequestPermissionResult and before finish and its giving the same issue

Comment: Can you adapt the code here in such a way please?

Comment: if (phoneLogsPermission && phoneCallPermision) {
registerBrodcasts();
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions granted, we can call now.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();

Comment: chill dude, I know in the post also but as I wrote in my question it does not work if I do that